# Experiment instrumentation & Measurements

Tags: oscilloscope, voltmeter

In doing the experiment on signal conditioning(rc band pass filter) why was the oscilloscope is a better choice than the voltmeter for voltage measurement?

Comment: You can actually trigger a nice looking waveform of the filter and observe its characteristics.  No voltmeter will ever do that to you.

Answer (score 0):

for a simple cct, if you follow the rules for CM input range (e.g. Vin bias =Vcc/2) for linear operation and R range due to current limits, a DMM shud do, but remember that they detect peak and convert by ratio to RMS assuming a sine wave.

If you haven't observed many unusual waveforms on a scope like driving long coax, then DMM may not tell you signal integrity issues due to mismatched impedance or common mode input noise RF immunity.

If not a Rail-Rail output type, then understand what limits are imposed and if,R-R understand they are usually low current types and sometimes noisy without some load.

Answer (score 0):

Summary:

"Meters" attempt to either track instantaneous values or to present some weighted single point indication of eg voltages , which are poor & "lossy" ways of presenting the available information.

An oscilloscope accepts data in a high speed serial format which your eye-brain system is not able to handle and converts it to a slowly varying 2D or 3D format which is designed to optimise its usability by your eye-brain system.

- Throughout, slow or fast are relative to the eye-brain systems achievable input and processing rate

**__________________________________**

**Detail:**

Your eye-brain system (EBS} is a parallel input 2D x slow time change input and processing system.

Electrical events often consist of time serial high speed signals which are well above the maximum design data rate that your sensors can acquire or that your processing system can deal with when presented in serial form.

An oscilloscope converts "serial time domain events" which are completely beyond the ability of your sensor system to acquire and/or of your processing system to process into one or a series of parallel static or slowly varying* 2D (or N x 2D or maybe 3D) display format that your brain-eye system is designed to handle.

For repetitive periodic variations such as eg sine, square, triangle, sawtooth, trapezoid waveforms the signal repeats consistently over a short and stable period. At more than say 10 Hz such waveforms become unintelligible to the EBS using meter measurements of instantaneous values. A synchonised oscilloscop may display one or a few or a selected part of such a repeated waveform and thereby explore in 2D what is only a representation of a rapidly repeating periodic signal. ie while the data rate is STILL high the periodic component is indicated by the instrument settings but extracted so the EBS does not have to deal with it.

Single shot or occasional events may be frozen and/or logged for examination in EBS-suitable space.

---

Example:

A 100 Hz 1V sinewave applied to an analig or digital meter which is able to follow it adequately is beyong the ability of your EBS to resolve. The same sine wave displayed as a static 2D image on an oscilloscope is immediately able to be handled by your EBS. Changing the signal to a triangle wave or a trapezoid MAY change the meter display, but not in a way which is understandable, whereas on an oscilloscope the nature of the change is immediate obvious.